# LDAP filter in substring

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

Let's say I have an attribute "AAAAA0A".
I want to make an ldap filter which searches for every attribute with 0 on the 6th place.

*0 * Returns attributes like these "00CDEFG" and thats not what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is no Matching Rules in LDAP that allows to match a character at a specific place in a string.
All LDAP defines is substring matching: Initial substring `(xxx*)`, middle substring `(*xxx*)` or ending substring `(*xxx)`. You can have a complex expression such as `(A*Foo*Bar*Z)`.